# Logging time when our full node receives data of a new block from Arbitrum feeder

Tags: go-ethereum, full-node, arbitrum

Per the title, I'm looking at logging the time when our full node receives data of a new block from the Arbitrum feeder. I'm using GETH to run our full node. Any idea which file I should be looking at to modify it to log this time stamp?